# Передача поискового запроса в карту через ссылку

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Коллеги, на странице есть Я.Карта, на ней контрол searchControl. Как в это поле передать значение?
С обычными картами это работает так: [https://yandex.ru/maps/?mode=search&text=Москва](https://yandex.ru/maps/?mode=search&text=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0)
А как быть с внедренной по API карте на своей странице?

Пример `<a href="mymapaddress/mode=search&text=Москва">Найти Москву</a>`
И вот в поле поиска попадает строка "Москва".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Инициировать поиск на карте, сделанной на JS API Карт, можно через метод поискового контрола `searchControl.search("текст поискового запроса")`.

То есть на своей странице вам нужно сделать какой-то параметр url для поискового запроса (как параметр text в вашем примере с Яндекс.Картами). Тогда при переходе на ваш сайт вы будете читать значение из нужного параметра и вызывать поиск методом API Карт, который я привела выше.

Comment: Добавлю, что в песочнице Яндекса есть рабочий пример на это: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/search_control_ppo

Comment: Добрый день. Да, про контрол я прочитал и даже нашёл пример в песочнице, который вы прислали. Вопрос в том, что как эта ссылка выглядеть должна, совсем этого не понимаю. По которой в этот searchControl данные и поступают.

Comment: А это вы должны сами придумать и закодить. Эта часть логики лежит вне API Карт, т.е. нет какого-то встроенного в API метода для создания таких урлов, только метод вызова поиска из моего ответа. А вот создать урл и передать значение в переменную - уже самостоятельная задача. Можете сделать соответствующий вопрос в теме вашего языка.